# Why does this loop always return false, when you enter the correct value?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Password {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please create a password");
        String pw = reader.nextLine();

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Enter the password");
            String pwt = reader.nextLine();
            if (pwt == pw) {
            System.out.println("The password is correct!");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("The password is incorrect, please try again");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to this, so the answer is probably obvious, but I just don't understand why it reads false when I type the right password

Comment: Yet another `String.equals` question

Comment: This is string compare problem: "if (pwt == pw) {" should be "if (pwt.equals(pw))"

Comment: so how would that be notated? would I put `pw.equals(pwt)`?

Comment: Here you are expecting input from system.in, so new object of string is creating i.e new String() each time rather than fetching object from String literal pool. And you are comparing those two object references with == which is identity check and obviously it always returns false since those two references point to different objects. If you use .equals then It'll return true since you are going to compare their state check.